# What is the benefit of installing correct driver for monitor in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display

I have a Dell U2312HM, but my Windows 7 x64 detect it as Plug n Play monitor.

What are the benefit of finding and installing the correct driver for it ? Sharper image? Custom resolution? Power-smart features?

Is it important to have the correct driver installed for monitor ?

Comment: They sometimes install colour profiles, which adjust the image so the colours are more accurate (I once had a monitor which had a yellow tinge until I installed the drivers from the CD). On older versions of Windows they add support for the monitor resolution and aspect ratio.

Answer (score 3):

A so-called "monitor driver" usually contains color profiles. They are absolutely positively optional. All consumer display devices use a set of well-defined interfaces to communicate with your computer. Power-saving features and the like work right away.

Considering how some programs use color profiles and others don't, you'll also get some visual discrepancies.

Comment: correctamundo.  the so called drivers are not drivers at all.

Answer (score 0):

> A driver is software that allows your computer to communicate with
>   hardware or devices. Without drivers, the hardware you connect to your
>   computer—for example, a video card or a printer—***won't work properly***.
>   http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ph/windows/what-is-driver#1TC=windows-7

You can download the driver [here](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Pages/Drivers/dell-u2312h.html).

In layman's term, drivers serve as the communicator or medium between your computer and the hardware connected to it. You must not install a driver intended for other hardware. The benefit is, you will be assured that your hardware will work ***fine*** with your computer, and avoid any glitches or malfunctions. Now, regarding the details on what are the *benefits*, that is very technical, I believe.

I am not sure why it is recognized as a Plug and Play hardware, though. But it is a best practice to install the appropriate driver always.

Answer (score 0):

The default Microsoft drivers do well most of the time, you should install those only if you intend to get a specific multi-screen/3D/mega-screen configuration...